# How To load data that are accessed from database to html form

Tags: html, forms, textbox, textarea

I am trying to access data from table with GetString() method  and that data is stored in some variable  then it  must be loaded to html form when i am click the  submit button. How to it? Please help me......

Answer (score 1):

This question is too general.

In order to access the database you need a web server running server-side code in a language such as ASP.NET, Java, PHP, etc. The server code would be responsible for using a "GetString()" method to read the table and populate data in the form (or even better, return it to an MVC View or to JavaScript via AJAX to load it onto the HTML form).